# Handling Jersey WS Timeout

Tags: java, jersey

I've seen posts about how to set the connect timeout for a Jersey client but the documentation doesn't really say how the timeout is handled?  Is an exception thrown?  If so what exception?

What I'm trying to do is catch the timeout so that the application can continue without the webservice.  I can't just let a runtime exception halt execution.

Comment: You should answer your own question then, and get the badge for it.

Comment: New users can't answer their own questions until 8 hours have passed.  I'll update it so it has an answer since enough time has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just need more sleep...obviously a unit test where I hit a non existent service would easily answer this question.  In fact it's SO obvious I wrote it yesterday before I got distracted by higher priority tasks and didn't remember it until I posted the question to SO.

The answer is that when you call post it will return com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException with the root exception being java.net.SocketTimeoutException